# Riemann Sum of $\int_1^b x^{-1/2}\,dx$ with $x^*_i=\frac{(\sqrt{x_{i-1}}+\sqrt{x_i})^2}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

I am trying to evaluate the integral
$$\int_1^b x^{-1/2}\,dx$$
with $b\in\mathbb{Z}_{>1}$ using Riemann sums. I consider the uniform partition
$$\mathcal{P}_n=\left\{1,1+\frac{b}{n},1+\frac{2b}{n},\dots,1+\frac{b(n-1)}{n},b\right\}$$
on $[1,b]$ and the Riemann sum
$$
R_n=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})f(x^*_i)
$$
where $$x^*_i=\frac{(\sqrt{x_{i-1}}+\sqrt{x_i})^2}{4}.$$ I am having difficulty evaluating $f(x^*_i)$. We have
\begin{align}
f(x^*_i)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x_{i-1}}+\sqrt{x_i}},
\end{align}
but how do we represent $x_{i-1}$ and $x_i$ to simplify this expression? Is there something wrong with my partition?

Comment: If you are allowed to use any partition you want, try $\{1,q,q^2,\ldots,q^n\}$ with $q=b^{1/n}$.

Comment: @David I can use any uniform partition. Is this partition preferable? I will try it now.

Comment: This is not a uniform partition.  If you have to use a uniform partition, then the one you posted is the only option.

Comment: @David Crap. Then I am still stuck.

Comment: Think carefully about the algebra:$$(x_i-x_{i-1})\frac{2}{\sqrt{x_{i-1}}+\sqrt{x_i}}$$can be simplified a lot.

Comment: The partition should consist of points $1+i\cdot\frac{b-1}{n}, i=0,1,2,\dots,n$ rather than $1+ib/n$.

Comment: Further I must say that the choice of points $x_i^{*} $ is very smart.